# Threads in server and methods

Tags: java

I have to make a Server which take from a client numbers as input  and output it in a text file. I am getting Following Error.
The error is :

> at java.io.BufferedReader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
>   java.io.BufferedReader.read(Unknown Source)
>   Server_thread.writeTxt(Server_thread.java:72)
>   Server_thread.run(Server_thread.java:49)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

and the code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class Server_thread implements Runnable{
     private Socket socket;
     private BufferedReader  instream=null;
     private BufferedWriter outstream=null;
     private FileWriter file=null;
     private Scanner scanner=null;
     private int number=0;
     private String strin;
        public Server_thread(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;

            Thread t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }


        public void run() {

            try {
                file = new FileWriter("C://Users//Vagos//Desktop//file.txt");

            try
            {
                instream = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (socket.getInputStream()));
                outstream = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));


                scanner = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));


                //strin = instream.readLine();

                if ((instream.readLine()).equals("Insert")){ //following the protocol


     writeTxt(); <--heare
            }else if((instream.readLine()).equals("Read") ){
                readTxt();
            }
                instream.close();
                outstream.close();
                file.close();
                socket.close();

          System.out.println("Waiting for client message...");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private synchronized void writeTxt() throws IOException{

        do{

        number = instream.read(); <--heare 
        file.write(new Integer(number).toString());
        file.write("   ");
        file.flush();
        }while(number!=100); //bye = terminate the conversation
    }

    private void readTxt() throws IOException{

         while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
               outstream.write(scanner.nextInt());
               outstream.flush();
            }
    }




}
```

Comment: That stack tells us *where* the error is occurring, but not *what* that error is.

Comment: You left off the first line of the error message, which is the most important one. Also, which line is the error happening on? Can you think of any reason there might be a problem on that line?

Comment: There's nothing *before* the error you show? Like what the error is?

Comment: sorry here all the error
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
 at java.io.BufferedReader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.read(Unknown Source)
 at Server_thread.writeTxt(Server_thread.java:72)
 at Server_thread.run(Server_thread.java:49)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)